# How to exclude exact strings (not substrings) from matches in regex?

Tags: regex

I've found lots of questions on here on how to exclude a substring from results, but I want to exclude lines that are exact matches and simply can't figure out how to do it.

With the test data below, how would I match everything *except* for `11` and `111`?

```
0
1
00
01
10
11
000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
```

I've tried various things, such as this:

```
^((?!11|111).)*$
```

But that excludes substring matches, when again I'm wanting to exclude exact matches.

Is this possible with regex? If so, how can excluding *exact* matches be achieved?

Comment: Maybe this is some non-regex task? I.e. doing some simple string comparisons, completely without regex?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have the end-of-line *included* in the negative look ahead:

```
^(?!(11|111)$).*$
```

[See live demo](http://rubular.com/r/z7I8wjJnwk) (using your data)

Without including the end-of-line, you are only asserting that the input doesn't *start* with `11` or `111`, when what you want is to assert is that the *entire* input (start to end) isn't `11` or `111`.

Answer (score 1):

Through PCRE verb `(*SKIP)(*F)`,

```
^(?:11|111)$(*SKIP)(*F)|.+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gB3uR8/3)

**OR**

```
^(?:(?!^(?:111|11)$).)++$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gB3uR8/5)

Comment: Why is your negative lookahead inside of the group? This will make the regex much slower...

Comment: And you can use `111?` to match `11` or `111`.